# Using select to switch images

Tags: jquery, select, image

I'm fairly new to jQuery and I am trying to switch image `src` attribute by getting the links from a `select` HTML tag.

This is the select HTML that I'm using:

```
<select id="pages">
  <option value="Manga/Naruto/Friends/01.png">1</option>
  <option value="Manga/Naruto/Friends/02.png">2</option>
  <option value="Manga/Naruto/Friends/03.png">3</option>
  <option value="Manga/Naruto/Friends/04.png">4</option>
</select>
```

This is the jQuery script that I'm trying to use in order to switch the image `src` attribute :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#pages").change(function(){
    $('#greatphoto').attr('src', val());
    //.val());
  }); 
</script>
```

And this is the placeholder for the images that I am trying to switch:

```
<div id="mangaImages">
  <img id="greatphoto" src="Manga/Naruto/Friends/01.png" />
</div> <!-- end of mangaImages -->
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
$(function() {
   $("#pages").change(function(){
      $('#greatphoto').attr('src', this.value); // Could use $(this).val() too.
   });
});
```

Wrapping your code with `$(function() {...});` makes sure that the DOM is loaded before it runs. This is a shortcut for calling jQuery's [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) method.

Right now your `<select>` is not getting the `change` event, because it doesn't exist yet when the code is running.

Answer (score 2):

You might try

```
$(this).val()
```

instead of

```
val()
```

Comment: Yep you still had other probs, check that other answer, for almost all basic jQuery operations you'll want to put the code inside a document ready event handler.